# Does Wordpress generate an automatic page for post formats?

Tags: wp-query, pages, post-formats

I want a page to view only a specific post format (e.g. aside).

Do I have to create my own page and run a custom query, or does Wordpress have an automatic page generated for me (like the categories)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at  [get_post_format_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format_link)

Here's a little example that uses `get_post_format_link()` to show a link to the format's archive page. You can see something similar to this in action on [Justin Tadlock's site](http://justintadlock.com/).

```
function get_post_format_archive_link() {
    return sprintf( 
        '<a class="post-format-archive-link %1$s" href="%2$s">%1$s</a>',
        get_post_format(),
        get_post_format_link( get_post_format() ) 
    );
}
```

usage:

```
echo get_post_format_archive_link();
```

The URL Structure is:

> ```
> /type/{post format}/
> ```

So for an aside we'd have:

> ```
> http://example.com/type/aside/
> ```

Comment: What's the difference between `get_post_format_link()` & `get_post_format_arhive_link()`?

Comment: @MegaHit `get_post_format_archive_link()` is just an example that uses the WP core function `get_post_format_link()`.  The output of  `get_post_format_archive_link()` makes styling the individual links easier, but `get_post_format_link()` does all the real work here.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add theme support for post formats with code.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery' ) );
```

The code above is what you'd put in your theme's `functions.php` file, and then in your template files, you would display each post accordingly with the following code, for example if your post format for a post was `video`:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
  echo 'this is the video format';
}
```

See the Codex for more info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats#Adding_Theme_Support

Comment: I already have theme support for the `aside` post format. What I want now is a page that displays *only* the posts with the `aside` post format applied to them. Now, I could create my own page and run a custom query, but I wanted to know if there's a pre-built page for that, similar to how Wordpress automatically creates pages for categories...

Comment: Unfortunately no, WordPress does not have that feature included by default. See this page for the official instructions on how to 'use post formats': http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats#Using_Formats -- Regardless of what you do you would still have to create a template with a query for that post format/list of posts in a post format or modify an existing one.

Comment: Or even more-so, if you were to get the archive link for the post formats, it would fallback and use your archive template, where you would need to edit that file to display posts differently for the post formats.