# Displaying all Video Post Formats to Page

Tags: post-formats, videos, template-hierarchy

I am creating a video-archive page for all the `posts_format` with `video`.

Currently, I have:

```
<?php $format = has_post_format('video', $post_id); ?>      

<?php

if($layout != "fullwidth") {
    echo '<div class="page_inner">';
}

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    vntd_blog_post_content();

endwhile;
```

This is not working, but I do not think I'm far off.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Post formats have automatically generated archive pages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39935/4771).

Comment: Then how would I display this archive page for only and all video post formats?

Comment: `http://example.com/type/video/`

Comment: I'm trying to add a archive-video.php file and also a single-video.php file to fill that URL. I've also tried taxonomy-video.php. No luck so far.

Comment: Perhaps I need first to register 'video' as a post type? Yet it appears in my post editing sidebar ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if you need a dedicated page or a true archive page for this, but here is the two options

If you need a dedicated page to display video post formats, you can make use of a custom query with a `tax_query` as `post_format` is just another build in taxonomy with `post-format-video` being a term to the `post_format` taxonomy. Your query on your page template should look something like this

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-video'
        )
    )
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post() );

        // Your loop

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

If you need to create a specific archive page for video post format only, you can create a special taxonomy template for this by simply copying your index.php template and renaming it to `taxonomy-post_format-post-format-video.php`. Everytime you visit this taxonomy page at `example.com/type/video` or you click on a `post-format-video` link, this template will be exclusively used to display video post format posts.

Reference: [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display)

### EDIT

Your comment

> `news.diginomics.com/type/video` What do I name my php file to take advantage of this URL hierarchy?

As I stated, you need a taxonomy template as `post_format` is one of the 4 build in taxonomies. For a video post format specific template, copy your index.php and rename it

```
taxonomy-post_format-post-format-video.php
```

This template will be used everytime you visit `news.diginomics.com/type/video`

For interest sake, please see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545) I have done about taxonomies

Comment: This is close but no dice: http://news.diginomics.com/type/video/

What do I name my php file to take advantage of this URL hierarchy?